# How to find the limit to infinity of the iterative function used in the Mandelbrot set with a fixed C.

Tags: calculus, fractals, iterated-function-system

I'm trying to do my math IA on the effect of changing complex constant c in the mandelbrot set on the series's convergence, but I don't know how to algebraically solve the limits for iterative functions, even when I can do so graphically and in tabular form.

For example, how do I algebraically find the limit to $x_n = x_{n-1}^2 - 0.6$, which I know graphically approaches $0.42$ at infinity?

Comment: what happens when you try to solve $x = x^2 - 0.6$ ? (this should work for C in the main cardioid of the Mandelbrot set, where iterations approach a fixed point, other C behave differently)